# Activity Reference In ContextMenu

Tags: android

```
public static class AdapterViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
public AdapterViewHolder(  View originalView) {
    super(new RecyclerContextMenuInfoWrapperView(originalView);
    ((RecyclerContextMenuInfoWrapperView)itemView).setHolder(this);
    yourActivity.registerForContextMenu(itemView);
    itemView.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(yourListener);
}
```

Can you please tell me that how can i get activity in viewholder?

Comment: Add full code of Adapter class

Comment: What for ? you are setting own listener with  `itemView.setOnCreateContextMenuListener` using both    `yourActivity.registerForContextMenu(itemView);` and
    `itemView.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(yourListener);` makes no sens... but prolly `originalView.getContext()` will point to an Activity ...

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `customRecyclerViewAdapter` than you can pass `ActivityInstance` from `mainActivity` to `customRecyclerViewAdapter`'s Constructor and than can use in nested class(View holder) Refer to example below.

/* constructor of customRecyclerviewadapter */

```
Context rcontext;
public ImageAdapter(Context a)
{
    rcontext = a;
}
```

/* nested class(View holder)*/

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{
    public ViewHolder(View item)
    {
           /* you can use here */
           rcontext;
    }
}
```